# Running code as an executable file gives me an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I have the following piece of code in a `.py` file:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import shutil
shutil.rmtree(f"{os.getcwd()}/Logs")
os.makedirs(f"{os.getcwd()}/Logs")
```

and when I convert this to an executable file using `chmod` and run it, it gives me an error saying

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/myname/Logs'

Why is this the case, when the `.py` file works just fine, and how do I fix this?

**Edit:**
I am running this from `/Users/myname/Desktop` not `/Users/myname`

**Edit:**
I apologise this was unclear, I want to delete and remake a folder called `Logs` in my current directory which I am running the file from (my Desktop), but all `os.getcwd()` and `Path.cwd()` gives me is `/Users/myname`, not `/Users/myname/Desktop`

Comment: There is no need to specify the full path; just `Logs` will be looked up in the current directory, by definition.

Comment: ... And you are probably in a different directory than you assume when it fails. Probably look up the definition of "working directory"; but in brief, it's wherever you last `cd`:ed at the prompt (though if you run an IDE, it might be running in your home directory, or wherever you happened to be `cd`:ed when you originally started it).

Comment: @tripleee As I edited, the current directory seems to be `/Users/myname` not `/Users/myname/Desktop` for some reason

Comment: So how *exactly* are you running the script?

Answer (score 0):

It because the `'/Users/myname/Logs'` doesn't exists so It can't be removed by `shutil.rmtree`.

You can try make the directory manually and run the script again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the folder, Python will raise an exception if it doesn't exist, ignore the exception and recreate the directory. Also, use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), it simplifies file operations immensely.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import shutil
from pathlib import Path

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logs = Path.cwd() / 'Logs'
    try:
        shutil.rmtree(logs)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
    logs.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

Comment: when I checked, `Path.cwd()` is still `/Users/myname/Logs`, not `/Users/myname/Desktop/Logs`, which is what I want to fix

Comment: `cwd` gives you the directory where you run the script file. You can hardcode `Path.home() / 'Desktop/Logs'` instead of `cwd` or run the script from desktop directory so that `cwd` points to desktop.

Comment: I wanted the file to be relative, not absolute, hence me using `os.getcwd()` at first.

Comment: Try running `python3 -c "from pathlib import Path; print(Path.cwd())"` from where you run the script, what do you get? Does it give you `/Users/myname/Desktop`?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you run the executable. At the prompt,

```
cd $HOME/Desktop
python3 ./myscript.py
```

runs the script in the Desktop directory, where apparently you want to run it.

```
cd $HOME
python3 ./Desktop/myscript.py
```

runs the script in your home directory, as that's where you last `cd`:ed to.

(If the script has correct permissions, there should be no need to explicitly specify `python3` before the script name - the shebang line you put there should suffice.)

If you are running the script from an IDE like IDLE, pyCharm, or VS Code, the IDE might be running in whichever directory was current when you started it, or your home directory simply because that's where graphical applications which you start from a system menu tend to run. Some applications allow you to change the working directory per project, or per file, or through an application preference.

If the script needs to run in a particular directory in order to work correctly, maybe think about allowing the user to pass in the directory they want it to operate on as a parameter.

As an aside, there is no need to explicitly call `os.getcwd()`; simply `Logs` refers to `Logs` in the current directory - that's very literally what "current directory" means.